# Strange Chrome font char display bug

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

Does anyone know why letters in Chrome are (just sometimes) displayed in chinese characters? Pls see the picture as I dont know how to explain it very well. In other browser you don't see this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this is a Helvetiva rendering bug. See the following link for a workaround:

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/J4dqHZD3dcs

it fixed it for me.